# WebWorks UI structure: All in one HTML, or separate files?

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

What is the right way to design the page structure of a WebWorks app? I'm using jQuery-mobile as well.

A: Should all the pages be in a single HTML, each page being a:

```
<div data-role="page">...</div>
```

B: Should pages be separated in different HTML files linking to each other?

I am currently using approach A, but the app is a slow when transitioning from a page to another. I suspect one of the reasons is the size of the single HTML that includes all pages.

Also another issue I'm having is that pressing the physical "back" button on the phone exits the app which is another reason I'm doubting my approach in having all pages in one HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very opinionated answer: You're using the wrong framework. jQuery Mobile is extremely bloated and I've seen it perform poorly even on recent iOS devices, not to mention BlackBerry's not exactly very performant OS.

If you continue to go down the jQuery Mobile route, I would still recommend you have all your pages in a single HTML file, not least because the user experience on WebWorks is a bit sub-par when moving between separate HTML pages. For example, you'll get very noticeable "white flashes" when you follow a link to a different HTML file, especially on older/less powerful devices (although you can mitigate that a bit by setting a background colour for your `rim:loadingScreen` element in the config.xml). It's up to you to decide whether that is better or worse than the slow transitions in jQuery Mobile.

As for the back button, you can override the default behaviour by attaching an event handler to the back key like so (don't forget to have the `blackberry.system.event` feature enabled in your config.xml):

```
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, function() {
  // Back key pressed, go back to previous screen
}
```

If you're still open to an alternative solution though, I highly recommend you give bbUI.js a try (https://github.com/tneil/bbUI.js) - it's a semi-official framework that looks a lot more at home on the BB than jQuery Mobile and is better optimised for the platform (e.g. allowing you to only load scripts that you need for the particular page you're showing at that very moment, working around some WebWorks/BB-specific issues, etc.) - combine it with Zepto (http://zeptojs.com/) which is a blazingly fast jQuery replacement and you'll end up with an app that is significantly less sluggish than a jQuery Mobile based one.

Comment: I agree that jQuery Mobile is bloated.  When I first heard about it, I expected it to be a leaner version of jQuery, but when I realized I had to load jQuery (33.18KB) plus jQuery Mobile (31.77KB), I switched to zepto.js (9.01KB via cdnjs.com) with a fallback to jQuery for IE (zepto doesn't work in IE), and rolled my own UI. A bit more work, but all the CSS for my site is less than 10KB, while jQuery Mobile's CSS is 11.25KB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use which ever way suits your project best.  For a large app, it's probably worth having a single "index.html" which then links off to several other pages. Can make editing your code easier as well.